# orderBy and $Index probleme in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looping through array of events and show it on front. There is directive "score" inside div, and I want to inject number of array element in the directive code using `$index`. Works fine until I tried to add `orderBy` to `ng-repeat`. And now `$index` works based on ordered list. Any suggestion how to inject number of current element of array?

data:

```
"events" : [{
"event_score" : [0,1]
},
{
"event_score" : [0,1]
},
...
]
```

This is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in events | orderBy:'match_time'">
  <score index="{{$index}}" user="{{screen_name}}"></score>
</div>
```

Comment: Not understood what you want to do.

Comment: I need to get number current of element "e" in array "events". In same order how it goes in array

Comment: I suppose [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22978169/1229023) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed assign `events` to a `$scope` variable?

```
  $scope.events = [{
    "event_score" : [0,1]
    },
    {
    "event_score" : [0,1]
    },
    ...
    ];

<div ng-repeat="e in events">
  Current item is {{$index}}
  <score index="{{$index}}" user="{{screen_name}}"></score>
</div>
```

which is pretty well how angularjs works :P

Then

`orderBy:'match_time'` will not work cause you don't have a key called `match_time` in your array( as i can see), so it will work if you have something like

```
 $scope.events = [{
        "event_score" : [0,1],
        "match_time": 5600
        },
        {
        "event_score" : [0,1],
        "match_time":4500
        }
        ];
```