# Angular get in-between indexes after orderBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

As you know after `orderBy` table loses its ordering and the `$index` value is from the sorted array, not from the original array. So if you pass an `items` array `['orange', 'banana','potato','apple']` to your `ng-repeat`, after an `orderBy` on the UI you will see them like this:

```
- apple   $index = 0
- banana  $index = 1
- orange  $index = 2
- potato  $index = 3
```

And if you now want to multi select items between `apple($index = 0)` and `orange($index = 2)` you might think that this will work:

```
for(index = 0; index <= 2; index++)
  console.log(items[index])
```

which is wrong, it will print : `[orange, banana, potato]`; not `[apple, banana, orange]`.

I am looking a way to get the interval indexes of the displayed array after an orderBy, any ideas?

**EDIT:** To clarify, assume that on UI you have sorted `items` and then you select apple and then select orange:

```
✓ apple
  banana
✓ orange
  potato
```

I want a way to know the `items` **in between those two selected**, so that I can select all in between, in our case `banana`.

Comment: you can simply use item instead of $index and get the original index by using $scope.items.indexOf(item). for a working example you can go to the following link.

http://jsfiddle.net/0uksemjs/

Comment: When you use a filter in the View, it is meant to format/modify the data for presentation purposes. Can you elaborate on *why* you need to the indices of the filtered/ordered array? And if it's more than for presentation purposes, then you should created an ordered copy of the array in the controller using `$filter("orderBy")`

Comment: @NewDev I need the indices because I want to multi select the items on the view, so if I select apple, and then shift select orange, I want orange to be selected automatically regardless `orderBy`

Comment: @anvarik, did any of the answers below address your question?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to approach this is to pre-filter the array in the controller and operate on that array.

```
$scope.orderedItems = $filter("orderBy")($scope.Items, "+");

$scope.multiSelect = function(minIdx, maxIdx){
  //...
  $scope.selectedItems = $scope.orderedItems.slice(minIdx, maxIdx);
}
```

Of course, in the View you would `ng-repeat` over `orderedItems` without a filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in orderedItems">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve by custom filter https://stackoverflow.com/a/22978169/1632286

```
app.filter('index', function () {
    return function (array, index) {
        if (!index)
            index = 'index';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i][index] = i;
        }
        return array;
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | index | orderBy:'Store.storeName'">
```

and then in HTML you can use item.index instead of $index.

This method is suitable for the collections of objects.

Please, take into account that this custom filter should be the first one in the list of all filters applied (orderBy etc.) and it will add the additional property index (the name is customizable) into the each object of the collection.

Comment: adding a filter on `index` does not solve my problem since it is not different then `items.indexOf('apple')` which is `3` and `items.indexOf('orange')` which is 0. What i want is to get the UI indexes, 0 and 2 so that I can access to 1, banana.

Answer (score 1):

Angular allows you to specify an alias for the data after filters have been applied. You could pass that alias into whatever method selected the items out of it along with the item or the `$index` which is the item's index within the ordered items.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: '+' as orderedItems">
    <a ng-click="itemSelected(orderedItems, $index)">{{item}}</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the appropriate approach. It shows the strength of Angular where these common tasks are handed from the framework, and you don't have re-invent the wheel in order to create them. +1