# deleting an element in ng-repeat with orderBy and track by is failing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby, angularjs-track-by

Here is the code

```
<tr ng-repeat="collection in collections | orderBy:'-modifiedDate' track by $index" ng-init="listIndex = $index">
```

If I remove `orderBy:'-modifiedDate'`, the deletion on a specific element is working great. However, I need the collection/array to be rendered in sorted way that's why I have orderBy.

If I don't delete the `orderBy:'-modifiedDate'` from the code and I delete a random element say on position 7, the element that gets deleted is the very last always.

I had to use `ng-init` since I have another `ng-repeat` inside the `ng-repeat` shown above. I call the delete function like this, `ng-click="deleteRow(listIndex)"`

Comment: Use ng-click="deleteRow($index)"

Comment: @neda, he has another ng-repeat , so he has to use the ng-init to push $index to listIndex if i got it correct.

Comment: @devwannabe, could you please add the `deleteRow` code as well?

Answer (score 0):

alert `listIndex` in the `deleteRow` method, if it is coming correct as 7, use `splice(listIndex,1)` to do the deletion.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just found a better way and it's working great now. This is the code I'm using now $scope.collections.splice($scope.collections.indexOf(item), 1); I got rid of the track by and listIndex too

Comment: Thank you. I posted my answer since I cannot format the one in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work.

in the template

```
<tr ng-repeat="collection in collections| orderBy:'-modifiedDate'">
 ........
 ... there is another ng-repeat here
   <a ng-click="deleteItem(collection)">Delete this item</a>
```

in the controller

```
  $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
      $scope.collections.splice($scope.collections.indexOf(item), 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, even more simple:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(array, index){
   array.splice(index, 1);
};
```

And in your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="collection in collections| orderBy:'-modifiedDate'">
 ..........
 ..........
 <a ng-click="deleteItem(collections, $index)">Delete this item</a>
```

Comment: That's the code I had earlier but with the presence of orderBy and track by, it deletes the last row even if the index is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you use orderBy, angular creates another "collections" in the scope, and changes the order of its elements, but the original "collections" stays the same, for example if :

```
    $scope.collections = [
    { name: '1st element', id: '1' },
    { name: '2nd element', id: '2' },
    { name: '3rd element', id: '3' }
];

<tr ng-repeat="collection in collections | orderBy:'id':true track by $index">
```

**$scope.collections[2]** would still be *{ name: '3rd element', id: '3' }*

Here's what you can do, you can give a name to that sorted collection created by angular :

```
<tr ng-repeat="collection in sortedCollections = (collections | orderBy:'id':true) track by $index">
```

And then you could use **$scope.sortedCollections[2]** instead