# AngularJS $index works incorrectly after orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a project where users can vote on items, and after an orderBy, the function works only on the original indexes of the items. I would like to track the items by their ID property which is pulled from the database but am having issues. I have also tried passing the objects rather than their indexes but again am having trouble getting my head around it.

Relevant JS

```
angular.module("cardSite", ['masonry'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
        $scope.cards = [];
        dataService.getCards().then(function(response) {
            $scope.cards = response.data;
        }, function() {});

        $scope.plusOne = function($index) {
            $scope.cards[$index].card_rating += 1;
        };
    });
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 tile grid-item" ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy : '-card_rating' | limitTo:8 track by card.ID">
<div class="panel panel-default {{ card.card_category | lowercase }}_panel">
    <p>Card ID: {{card.ID}}</p>
    <!DOCTYPE svg>
    <p ng-click="plusOne($index)"> Vote up</p>
    <p>{{card.card_rating}}</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118904/820942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need your index in this case?

You could just pass the object directly :

```
<p ng-click="plusOne(card)"> Vote up</p>
```

And change your function to:

```
$scope.plusOne = function(card) {
        card.card_rating += 1;
};
```

Comment: I was overcomplicating the problem it seems, this was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Np! Easy to overthink things! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue:)

Comment: Was just waiting for the 10 minutes to run out! Thanks again