# $index not working properly with OrderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in currDateByMsg[msgDate.strDate]|orderBy :'-SendMsgDate':true">
     <div ng-if="!msg.currentUser">
       <div data-ng-if="$first || (currtDateByMsg[msgDate.strDate][$index].userId !=
         currDateByMsg[msgDate.strDate][$index -1].userId)">
         <img class="img-circle" ng-src="{{msg.iconPath}}"/> 
       </div>
     </div>
     <div>{{msg.userMessage}}</div>
</div>
```

i want to skip images when more than on message come from same user(i.e- show only one image).I'm iterating in reverse order but $index value is taking from 0. so how i reverse the index value too.

Comment: $index is an iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1), it will be always start from 0, order by will reverse the data by SendMsgDate. so at $index = 0 you will get the last item.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118762/angularjs-wrong-index-after-orderby) out, the answer by mile should help you solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Store it first

```
var len = (currDateByMsg[msgDate.strDate].length-1);
```

then

```
$index + len
```

In html.